# Ajax call to get json not working on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need some help with the application I'm creating.

I'm using jquery 11 and I need to retrieve a json file using ajax.
The problem is that the code works ok in desktop browsers but no if I run the application on a mobile.
I'm also using bootstrap 3 (it requires to use jquery) so I think I cannot also add Jquery mobile. Does anybody know how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance :)
Cheers

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/mobile/json/staffing.json',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(json)
        {
            alert("loaded");
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("not working")
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: You refer to `localhost` and I just assume you are running a local server during development and in your browser all's good. But your phone doesn't have `localhost`. Replace it with your IP (and you should be in the same WiFi as your desktop).

Comment: To help the testing of what @christian314159 has said, I'm putting a dummy `staffing.json` file on my server for you to try getting in case you don't have your own out there.  Replace your `...localhost:8080/...` url with this: `http://www.bink-e.com/staffing.json`