# jQuery on Button Click in mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, button, mobile

I have a Button

```
 d3.select("#updatebutton").on("click", function(e) {
       try{
            $.get('any url', function(data) {
                    alert('Any Alert Message');
                window.location.href = window.location.href;
            });
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert('Error: ' + e);
        }
    }
```

where i want to do certain actions on the button click event:

```
 app.get('any url', function(req, res, next) {
try{
    anyfunction();
}
catch(e) {
    alert('Error');
}
});
```

It is working fine on normal web browser, however if I open my webpage on a mobile device, it seems that the click event is never called and nothing happens. Is this a jQuery Problem or am I missing something?

The Code is running on a node.js Server.

Hope anyone can help.

UPDATE:

I'm using jade as rendering-engine for HTML. My Button looks like the following:

```
    div#updatebutton
    i.fa.fa-repeat.fa-lg
    |   'some description'
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle which does not work on mobile ? You can use `chrome://inspect` to debug..

Comment: I don't really know how to make a example fiddle as the `$.get('any url', function(data) {}` is an ajax call between server and client side.... This may be the real problem, is ajax working on mobile devices like this? @RayonDabre

Answer (score 1):

Try with `touchstart` event.

**UPDATE**

Please check.

```
var myButton = d3.select("#updatebutton");
myButton.on("touchstart", onDown);

function onDown() {
    alert("Work");
    try{
        $.get('any url', function(data) {
            alert('Any Alert Message');
            window.location.href = window.location.href;
        });
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert('Error: ' + e);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok please try the update. if dont work, check if you have an error in your debug console

Comment: this is not working cause the whole page is a d3 graph. If I add `var myButton = ...` the whole graph crashes. is there no other solution?

Comment: ok, I found the problem! in `$.get('any url', ....)` I am using localhost in any url! If I Change localhost to my local IP all is working fine! But now it is not working on my normal webbrowser! Does anyone know how to get it on both device types working?@P. Frank

Comment: ok it's work with `myButton.on("touchstart", onDown);`? if yes just add  `myButton.on("touchstart click", onDown);`

Comment: no sry for missunderstanding! your solution is not working at all for my code. What I find out is, based on my code i posted in the initial post above, that in the `$.get('https://localhost:4444/data', function(data) {}` the 'localhost' is the problem. If I change localhost to my servers IP-Adress the request is working fine on mobile browser, but not on my desktop/server browser anymore. How can i make both browser types recognize the request? @P.Frank

Comment: "You refer to localhost and I just assume you are running a local server during development and in your browser all's good. But your phone doesn't have localhost. Replace it with your IP (and you should be in the same WiFi as your desktop)." christian314159 answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23901366/ajax-call-to-get-json-not-working-on-mobile-browsers.   Try replace "https" by "http"

Comment: yes thats it! now the click-event is working on mobile browsers. but now, it is not working on my desktop browser anymore. How to make it work on both? @P.Frank

Answer (score 0):

> You can detect user device using `navigator` object. Refer [this](https://ctrlq.org/code/19616-detect-touch-screen-javascript)

If device is `touch` enabled then use `touchstart`/`touchend` events or use `click` events for `desktops`(`click` events should work in mobile browsers too, can not guess the reason by going through the provided code)

Try this:

```js
function is_touch_device() {
  return (('ontouchstart' in window) || (navigator.MaxTouchPoints > 0) || (navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0));
}
var myButton = d3.select("#updatebutton");
var myEvent = is_touch_device() ? 'touchend' : 'click';
myButton.on(myEvent, onDown);

function onDown() {
  $.get('any url', function(data) {
    alert('Any Alert Message');
    window.location.reload(); //better way to reload the page
  }).fail(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```